# MySQL Relational Query -- is JOIN the answer?

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, self-join

I'm writing a basic forum system for my site using MySQL. I need a way to track not only posts, but responses **TO** the posts. Since each post can only have **ONE** parent, but can ultimately have **MULTIPLE** children, I'm thinking I need two tables. The first table contains at a minimum the titles, the bodies and the parent of each post. The second table contains only a reference to **PARENT** posts and their corresponding **CHILDREN**, like so:

```
Posts Table

ID |  PARENT  |  TITLE  |  POST
1  |          |  Msg 1  |  Body 1
2  |          |  Msg 2  |  Body 2
3  |          |  Msg 3  |  Body 3
4  |  2       |  Msg 4  |  Body 4
5  |  1       |  Msg 5  |  Body 5
6  |          |  Msg 6  |  Body 6
7  |          |  Msg 7  |  Body 7
8  |  5       |  Msg 8  |  Body 8
9  |          |  Msg 9  |  Body 9
10 |  1       |  Msg 10 |  Body 10
11 |  1       |  Msg 11 |  Body 11
12 |  2       |  Msg 12 |  Body 12


Children Table

ID |  PARENT  |  CHILDREN   
1  |  2       |  4           
2  |  1       |  5 
3  |  5       |  8 
4  |  1       |  10 
5  |  1       |  11
6  |  2       |  12
```

In this example, Message 1 has 3 children: 5, 10 & 11. Message 2 has 2 children: 4 & 12. Etc.

Armed with this information, I'm trying to find the best way to determine the children of a **subset** of my Posts list (Say Messages 5 thru 10)? Would a JOIN of some sort allow a single query to get the parents *and* any corresponding children? Or am I better served doing separate queries on each parent message to determine its children?

I'm trying to get my head around JOIN and it's confusing as heck. Sorry if this is basic stuff, but thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no need for both tables. The parent information in the first table is the same as in the second table.

Comment: To get the parents *and* their children you need a `UNION`. One subquery just gets the parents, the other is a `JOIN` that gets their children.

Comment: @Barmar I realize if I was querying the entire table, I'd be able to constitute all the dependencies. However, if you LIMIT your query, you can have parent posts that far precede the query range. And those parents, additionally, could have many other children, also preceding (or following) the query range. That is my problem. I'll read up on UNION. Also going to read up on SELF-JOIN. Does that have any application in this solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would use a self-join if you just use the `Posts` table without the `Children` table.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. I'm focusing my study on `SELF-JOIN` right now, based on your guidance. But honestly it's hurting my brain. If you have any gentle guidance on how to structure such a query, given the example tables I've provided, I would be forever in your debt. If not, I'm certain I'll figure it out sometime in the next 6 months. :)

Comment: This is a faq. Please google clear statements of your question/problem/goal before considering posting. Google re sql recursive/heirarchical queries with & without 'mysql'. MySQL now has CTEs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select parent, group_concat(title) from posts where 
parent!='' group by parent;
```

Start here and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm still studying this, and will keep doing so, but an initial attempt has returned no result.

Comment: If your table and column names were correct, that query should return a result.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Not sure where my typo was before, but I definitely now get results. I have to dig into this and see how to limit my query to a subset of the list, and also return parents with no children.